# Java, jTable search

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

***This is NetBeand GUI code. I need help with that specifically.***
How do I get this code to append whole row in witch the asked element is to TextArea:

```
String trener1 = jTextField9.getText();
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
    int mCol = model.getColumnCount();
    int mRow = model.getRowCount();
    for(int i = 0; i < mCol; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < mRow; j++){
            if(jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(i, j).equals(trener1)){
                jTextArea1.append(model.getValueAt(i).toString()+ "\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Code should do:** I have a list of gym members. Informations about them are in table, their name, age, instructor. When I type the name of the instructor in one TextField, I want all names of members that have that instructor to get appended to TextArea.
Same with their age.

Comment: Don't describe the data in the table -- descriptions can be ambiguous. It's much more clear to just post a sample of the data. Your code also doesn't demonstrate how the instructor is related to gym members. Is there an instructor column? Is the instructor referred to with an id, or a name, or what? If you want a good answer, you need to improve this question.

Comment: Instructors have one column in table. It's just a string name of instructor.

Comment: *Instructors have one column in table.* - so you write a loop to check the instructor for each row (you don't loop through the columns yet). When you find a match you get the other data from each column for the current row.

Comment: Yes, I want to write only names of members that work with that instructor. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: What are you talking about? Your own code already has the answer. You get data out of your table model using getValueAt(). You know what row matches because that's the index where the instructor's name matches.

Comment: *If this code worked* - and you have been given a suggestion on how to improve the code. I haven't seen you update your code showing what you tried. Coding is about logic. You don't learn logic from a test book. If the instructors name is only contained in a single  column is it logically to test all columns for the name? You are making your code too complicated. You check each row for the instructor and then do something when you find the instructor.

Comment: *when I used getValueAt() it told me that it's not accepting int types* - no ideas what you are suggesting. The two parameters are int values. If you have a problem. Then post the actual error message and the statement causing the problem. If you need more help post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Please don't be so aggressive. I didn't change my code because suggestions don't mean to me anything, I need actual code example. I tried searching for how to use column name for this and found bunch of overcomplicated codes that are not even for GUI. I get the logic how to do it, but I cant find a simple way that would allow me to do it. I'm a beginner who didn't have a decent class for Java. We don't even know how to use class and objects in Java, witch is sad...but that's all I have for now.

Comment: I have one idea. To move column with instructors to be with index 1 and to try something like this: String trener1 = jComboBox5.getSelectedItem().toString();
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
    int mCol = model.getColumnCount();
    int mRow = model.getRowCount();
    for(int i = 0; i < mCol; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < mRow; j++){
            if(jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(i, j).equals(trener1)){
                jTextArea1.append(model.getValueAt(1,j).toString());
            }
        }
    } What do you think?

Comment: There is nothing to search. Every method that you need to use to solve the problem is already included in your original code. The issue is about logically ordering the code  I don't know how to explain any clearer that you only need a single loop. You loop through all the rows (you don't loop through the columns). I have no idea why you are talking about a "column name". If your instructor name is in column 3, then you get the value for column 3 and row "j" to see if it matches. If it matches, then you get the data from other columns and add the data to the text area.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216457/discussion-between-misteroggy-and-camickr).

Comment: There is nothing to chat about. I have explained the solution as clearly as I can. It is up to you to take the information given and revise the code you have posted. Don't post code in a comment. As you can see it is not readable.

Comment: Well I still don't know how do I make a code that does the job. But thanks for your help. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: What part about *you only need a single loop. You loop through all the rows (you don't loop through the columns)* do you not understand?

Comment: Well idk if it's possible to go through table if not as through matrix. That's all. What I want to do is just find a cell that has the data I need and then print all rows that has that data in it. So Instructor column is last in the table, name of the gym member is second column. I need to find all rows that have instructor John in it and print only names of gym members from those rows.

Comment: *Well idk if it's possible to go through table if not as through matrix* - Why are you talking about a matrix. If you know the instructor is in column 2, why do you need to check column 0 and column 1??? For each row in the table you only need to use `getValueAt(row, 2)` to see if the instructor names matches. If it does, then you get the values from the model using `getValueAt(row, 0)` and `getValueAt(row, 1)` and add them to the text area. My last comment unless you add some code showing you have made an effort.

Comment: Now you see, what you just wrote means something to me. I'll try with that. Thank you.

Comment: Done. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

That's it. Solved.

```
String trener1 = jComboBox5.getSelectedItem().toString();
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
    int Row = model.getRowCount();
    for(int i = 0; i < Row; i++){
            if(jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(i, 8).equals(trener1)){
                jTextArea1.append(model.getValueAt(i, 1).toString());
            }
    }
```

Comment: I hope you understand now why we explained the logic behind solving the problem instead of just writing code for you. You're taking a class. Your goal is to learn. You learn by doing. The only suggestion now is you might not want to hard code those column numbers. Put them in variables and use the variable so that your code doesn't break if you change your table model in the future.